# javascript template inheritance

Tags: javascript, templates

In the Django framework, web page templates can inherit from other templates. In your child template, you define blocks of code which override like-named blocks in parent templates. I'm guessing there are other back-end templating systems which also work this way, but Django is the one I'm familiar with.

Do any of the existing javascript template systems support django-style inheritance?

Comment: You should explain what "django-style inheritance" is and then maybe someone will post an answer.

Comment: Just [created my own question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7014944/207894) regarding this issue, with more detail. Hope this'll help.

Comment: Have a look at http://nunjucks.jlongster.com/ It's inspired by Django's jinja2 and provides a beautiful way of template inheritance.

Answer (score 6):

What you're looking for if you want template inheritance and DTL syntax, is **Nunjucks** :

http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/

Answer (score 0):

Mustache.js has support for [partials](http://github.com/janl/mustache.js/), which work in a similar* manner.  Other than that, I haven't been able to find anything -- maybe I'll make it ...

`*` Okay, they're not really like Django's templates *at all*, but they are the closest simulacrum I could find.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Template have a {{wrap}} template tag which is similar to extend:

http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-wrap/

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not "template inheritance", but
Beard.js can help you re-use your template by creating template references, which I think can help you achieve the same goal.

http://jspopisno1.github.com/Beard/#exmp_syntax-reference

Answer (score 0):

Check out Handlebars.js.  It allows you to define helper methods that you could use to compartmentalize different blocks, and echo them out, in a way similar to Rails' `content_for :my_area` and `yield :my_area`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with [Dustjs](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/), you can have a template inherit the bulk of its content from a common base template. Here is how it works, with [Dustjs](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/): (see the "Blocks and Inline Partials" section)

In a file "base_template":

```
Start
{+title/}
Middle
{+main/}
End
```

A template that "inherits" the base_template:

```
{>base_template/}
{<title}
  Child Title
{/title}
{<main}
  Child Content
{/main}
```

Results in something like:

```
Start
Child Title
Middle
Child Content
End
```

Related question: Only 1 level of inheritance seems to be supported: [Is there a way to do more than one level of inheritance value overrides with dust.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268522/is-there-a-way-to-do-more-than-one-level-of-inheritance-value-overrides-with-dus)

Answer (score 0):

There's some work in progress on adding template inheritance to **[Handlebars](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/)**.

See this fairly recent GitHub issue: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/208
And this blog post: [Template Inheritance for Handlebars](http://thejohnfreeman.com/blog/2012/03/23/template-inheritance-for-handlebars.html)