# Client-Side (JavaScript) Django/Jinja-like template inheritance

Tags: javascript, django, templates, django-templates

I'm looking for a way to do template inheritance to a group of `.html` files I have.

Let's say I have a `base.html` file which has the common HTML for all pages of my website, i.e. header, footer, etc. . Each page, including the main (index) page, needs to inherit from this template HTML file.

Now, this is doable on the server-side using [Django's Jinja template langauge](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance). But this is not a good solution for me. My HTML pages are stored remotely and I have no control over the server storing them. This must be done client-side, with or without JavaScript.

[Somebody asked about this before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3654963/207894), and the only half-baked solution I found was to use [Mustache's *partials*](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js), which doesn't really do the job.

Does anybody know of a way to do this on the client-side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.
Yes, with Dustjs you can *"have a template inherit the bulk of its content from a common base template"*.

Check out the Dustjs docs, here: [Dustjs](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/), the "Blocks and Inline Partials" section.

(I posted an answer to a related question,  here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12432034/694469 )

---

2.
There's also some work in progress on adding template inheritance to **[Handlebars](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/)**, see another answer of mine to "the other version" of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12432490/694469.

It links to this GitHub issue: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/208, and this blog post: [Template Inheritance for Handlebars](http://thejohnfreeman.com/blog/2012/03/23/template-inheritance-for-handlebars.html)

Answer (score 9):

I just released this for the same purpose: https://github.com/ericclemmons/jinja.js

Answer (score 1):

Jade offers full template inheritance: https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a11

In addition to overriding a block entirely, you can also append or prepend content to a block. Here is an example hijacked from the documentation:

Define a base template in layout.html:

```
html
  head
    h1 My Site - #{title}
    block scripts
      script(src='/jquery.js')
  body
    block content
    block foot
      #footer
        p some footer content
```

Append some script tags and replace the content section in content.html:

```
extends layout

block append head
  script(src='/vendor/three.js')
  script(src='/game.js')

block content
  .sidebar
    block sidebar
      p nothing
  .primary
    block primary
      p nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Template have a [{{wrap}}](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-wrap/) template tag 
 which can be used for this.

Comment: I don't think this allows template inheritance, just the same behaviour like Mustache's partials. Are you sure about that?